# Twitter bootstrap div alignment

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center form in twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172651/how-to-center-form-in-twitter-bootstrap)

I want to align my form in the center of the page, is there nay way to do it in **twitter bootstrap**? or i have to do it in same old custom way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).
Try the following:

```
<div class="span3 offset3">
   <form></form>
</div>
```

Comment: it worked some how but how i can add to margin in it?