# How to center form in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 center">
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <td>foo</td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bha64/)

Note: I am using an abstracted layer so am unable to change the class of `<form>`.

**How do I get the form centred using Twitter-Bootstrap?**

FYI: I have also tried with `pagination-centred`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both answers posted are valid and work so I upvoted them. Here is another method i did not see posted.

You can center your form by setting it to `display:inline-block` and center it within the `.center` container using `text-align:center`. This way the form will center regardless of width within that container:

**CSS**

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
}

.center form {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but also changed the text-alignment of my labels and input areas. So I had to had extra CSS to fix them.

Answer (score 59):

The native way for positioning elements in Bootstrap is using `offset`. I will assume that you are using a 12-column layout.

### Bootstrap 2

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <form>
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Further information in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

### Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <form>
                ...
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Further information in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Comment: Thanks, `offset4` almost looks right, but I think I'm looking for somewhere between `offset3` and `offset4`... i.e.: centred

Answer (score 7):

This is where i found my answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084576/1140407

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9 centred">
      This div will be centred.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and to CSS:

```
[class*="span"].centred {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
.center form {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

This is the easy and fast solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing like good ol' CSS?

```
.center > form {
  width: 300px; // some amount to prevent using 100% width
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And change `.span6` to `.span12`

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bha64/2/).
​

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
```

you coding for form

`</div>`