# Center a form in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using bootstrap 3.

What's the best way to center my form horizontally?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        //form stuff here
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172651/how-to-center-form-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Nope. That refers to bootstrap 2

Comment: You can use column offsets to center it if you want to use the grid system. Does your actual `<form>` have a `.col-*` class applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can add some styles to your form,

```
form {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:200px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sqHXG/1/)

Comment: Yes, but isnt there a bootstrap way of doing it?

Comment: Still doesnt work. You can;t set a width, that's not how bootstrap works.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to center your form you have two option:

1. you can use it inside a (col-) with the value you want (e.g: col-sm-6).
2. you can use it inside a (col-sm-12)

and either way you will need to use this css code:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  max-width: 550px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

the important is always use **max-width** and your value so the form field stay at this value in larger size and decreased in smaller size.

**update:**

use the above css code and use this code with your form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<legend class="righter">Legend</legend>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="col-lg control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="..." />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id" class="col-lg control-label">UUID</label>
    <div class="col-lg">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

important use **class="col-lg"** as the example above.

hope this will help , or upload live code for your form so i can help.

Comment: My fields go absolutely tiny when im on a large screen?