# Center horizontal form in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How would I center a horizontal form in bootstrap 3.2?  (in relation to the form container).

You can see my example at http://www.bootply.com/odXfJPlHRV

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="signup" style="width:800px;border:1px solid black">
<form class="form-horizontal no-margin center-block">
    <div class="form-group center-block">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group last-form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create an account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: in relation to what? the page, parent div? width, height, width&height? be more specific ... and, what have you tried?

Comment: In relation to the form container.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172651/how-to-center-form-in-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

in the CSS in the container?

http://www.bootply.com/drEdh7T8Cd

Or the form within the div:

http://www.bootply.com/AlDBmmEtin

Comment: That doesn't center it at all, unfortunately.

Comment: are you trying to center the div or center the form within the div?

Comment: Form within the div, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Like this you mean? (Black line is form, Red orginal div) http://www.bootply.com/AlDBmmEtin

Answer (score 1):

Swap classes with `.col-xs-2` for `.col-xs-6`.

Then apply a `text-align: right;` to the `<label>` and a `text-align:left;` and set a fixed `width` to the `<input>`

If you want to add more space between label - input add `col-xs-offset-*`

Check to see if this is the intended result:

[BOOTPLY DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Qc9sm6jrqk)

Comment: Doesn't work, now the label starts at the center, but I want the content centered.

Comment: added demo to OP ... check if this is the intended result

Answer (score 1):

On approach would be using [`col-*-offset-*` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to shift the labels and the button to the right to get it centered - [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/SC3A16nVEa).

It this case where each label and input have `.col-xs-2`, there would be `6` columns available. Therefore you could use `col-xs-offset-3` as follows:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="signup">
<form class="form-horizontal no-margin">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="control-label col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">Email</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group last-form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create an account</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <div class="row_fluid">
         <div class="span3">&nbsp; </div>
         <div class="span6"> Add your form in here </div>
         <div class="span3">&nbsp; </div>
    </div>
```